# Single switch circuit to turn on/off an LED

Tags: led, switches

I have very basic knowledge of electronics.

I am looking for a circuit which can turn ON/OFF an LED from a single switch.

- If the LED is OFF and the switch is pressed (even if not released) then the LED should turn ON.
- If the LED is ON and the switch is pressed (even if not released) then the LED should turn OFF.

A switch can be a push to ON switch but turns OFF when released. It is not like a toggle switch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What parts are available to you? Would a D-Flip Flop work?

Comment: Hi Tyler, I have 555 timer IC but can get other items as well. Just need a really simple solution to achieve this.

Comment: Your solution is right [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Foc9R0dC2iI). It's called a "Soft Latching" power switch. Check it out

Comment: @ezra_vdj If the button is not released then the circuit will oscillate; the LED will flash.

Comment: @CharlieHanson If it's good enough for Dave Jones I'd say it's good enough. All depends on project, cost, who's using it etc though, you feel?

Comment: @ezra_vdj The OP implies that oscillation is not acceptable with "pressed (even of not released)". It may be good enough for Dave Jones - and plenty of others as this is one of the oldest tricks in the book - but if it violates part of the specification then it is not the solution.

Comment: Yep I don't want a flashing LED. Anyways thanks everyone for your time and help. I thought it will involve few components but I don't think there is any such design. I have to manage 10 LEDs and these designs will make my project bulkier. I have to find something else then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is fairly simple: -

[image]

Each time you press the button, the output latches in the opposite sense to what it previously was. Lots of good ideas.

Picture stolen from this stack exchange question: [Make a Latching Relay using SPDT Relays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148296/make-a-latching-relay-using-spdt-relays)

Is this question all but identical?

Comment: Thanks Andy. The circuit looks OK but will not fit my project as I have to manage multiple LEDs. May be 10 or something. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Here is my exact requirement. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196598/circuit-to-indicate-1-to-10-based-on-pressed-switch-non-latching

Comment: I have answered this question for a single channel. Just step and repeat for multiple channels. I don't see the problem unless, of course, you have changed your mind about what you want.

Comment: I haven't changed my mind. I was looking for a circuit with less number of components. However, your answer seems to be more accurate than others. Thanks for your help.