# 2 momentary switches to control a pump

Tags: switches, relay, circuit-design, dc-motor

I would like to use 2 momentary switches to controle a water pump (start stop). When you press start the pump should run until I press stop or there is a power outage. The pump should also be off when the power is back on again until I press start. What type of relay should I use and how should I wire it?

Comment: question has been asked a number of time. It's called a latching relay.

Comment: It has to be unlatching too without power so the latching is not using a latching relay

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  I might call it a latching relay circuit, rather than just a latching relay.  You need a circuit around a normal relay wired so the relay latches itself on, but drops out when the power fails.

Comment: For a motor, requiring more than 200 watts or so, the relay should have an AC motor power rating. For smaller motors, the current rating should be considerably higher than the full-load rating of the motor to safely handle starting current and disconnecting a stalled motor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Latching Relay using SPDT Relays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148296/make-a-latching-relay-using-spdt-relays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical motor control switch/relay circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHe69A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Peter Bennett, this is great!!! I really appreciate it a lot.